# How to ensure a CSS grid has cards with fixed width and height using Tailwind CSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS and React to build an app, and in one of view I have a grid of cards. Currently it looks something like this:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

As you can see, the cards squeeze in as I make the window smaller. I want to ensure that the cards size (width and height) always stays the same, and it just moves to the next row if the amount of cards don't fit on one row as the window gets smaller.

Something like (made in MS paint):

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Where the size of the cards stay fixed (same aspect ratio) even though the screen is getting smaller.

Here's how my code looks currently:

Grid:

```
<div>
    <ul className="grid grid-cols-1 gap-4 sm:grid-cols-2 sm:gap-4 md:grid-cols-6 md:gap-4 lg:grid-cols-8 lg:gap-4">
        {props.trips.map((trip: TTrip) => (
            <TripCard trip={trip} href={currentPath + trip.id} />
        ))}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Card:

```
    <li
        key={props.trip.id}
        className="card card-compact shadow-xl col-span-1 w-128 h-fit bg-gray-100 hover:bg-base-200"
    >
        <div className="relative w-128 h-32">
            <Image src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/arch" layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <h2 className="card-title">{props.trip.name}</h2>
            <h2>Time - Time</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Any idea how to set this up using `tailwind-css`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you wanted to set this up using Grid, but unfortunately, it is not the right tool for this job. Flexbox would be best suited for your needs.
Here is a [tailwind playground that shows your desired output](https://play.tailwindcss.com/eE9CIbqGiu?layout=preview&size=704x439). The playground I linked doesn't use NextJS, as it does in your example. So, I have modified a few things such as images, as they are non-NextJS specific.

I have modified the styling a bit, in a way I felt is more efficient. Namely, I have moved the width setting from the image, to the container div. You can further modify this setup, as per your requirement.

In your setup, the code would translate roughly like this.

```
// Grid
<div>
    <ul className="flex flex-row gap-4 flex-wrap">
        {props.trips.map((trip: TTrip) => (
            <TripCard trip={trip} href={currentPath + trip.id} />
        ))}
    </ul>
</div>

// Card
    <li
        key={props.trip.id}
        className="card card-compact shadow-xl col-span-1 w-32 md:w-72 lg:w-96 h-fit bg-gray-100 hover:bg-base-200"
    >
        <div className="relative h-32">
            <Image src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/arch" layout="fill" objectFit="cover" />
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">
            <h2 className="card-title">{props.trip.name}</h2>
            <h2>Time - Time</h2>
        </div>
    </li>
```

Here's how it would look:

#### Largest with wrapping

[image: Largest with wrapping]

#### Medium without wrapping

[image: Medium without wrapping]

#### Small without wrapping

[image: Small without wrapping]

#### Small with wrapping

[image: Small with wrapping]

The exact breakpoints where the size and wrapping changes, depends on how you decide to implement it. If you are unhappy with the above points, you can simply modify the `lg`, `md` prefixes, as per your needs.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the response and the demo! In your playground it still seems like there is some squeezing (aspect ratio changes) as you make it smaller. Is this more or less unavoidable since it has to dynamically fit items as the screen gets smaller?

Comment: @FlameDra No, it is avoidable. In my playground, I have set the height to `h-32` on all three sizes (default, `md` and `lg`), while I have increased the width from `w-32` to `w-72` to `w-96`, as the screen size increases. If you wish to maintain a constant aspect ratio for the image or the card, you can either a) add the changing height values (`md: h-49 lg:h-60`) as per the required aspect ratio, or b) add the aspect ratio utility class (`aspect-square` or  a custom value like `aspect-[1/2]`). I would suggest the former, since I have run into bugs with aspect ratio, on other projects.

Comment: If I were the person implementing this, I would set the height and width on the `li` of the card, like `h-32 lg:h-40 w-64 lg:w-80` (Note that the aspect ratio remains fixed as `2/1` `width/height`, and set the image inside to be a percentage of the container height `h-1/4 w-full`

Comment: That worked great! Thanks for the answer! Its interesting how `grid` isn't the right utility to create a grid in this case!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of getting this done is via `flex` and `flex-wrap` and setting fixed desired height and width for the cards

##### Code Structure:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap">  Use flex flex-wrap
    <card>
    <card>
    <card>
</div>
```

---

#### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/BuwttL6OTV)

---

#### Code:

```
<div class="flex flex-wrap">
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-56 rounded-lg bg-gray-200 shadow-lg">
    <div class="h-40"><img src="https://placeimg.com/500/225/hous" class="h-full" /></div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-4xl">Title</div>
    <div class="pl-2 text-2xl">Subtitle</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Output in different screens:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Yeah, using flexbox works great for this. Thanks!